# How to check what sub-string follows follows a string matched by InStr

Tags: vba

I am trying to use the function `InStr` to find a specific string in another string.

When I find it, I would like to check what directly follows this string (for example *End-user*) and return this portion. So far I Have managed to write this:

```
If InStr(LCase(analysis), "End-user:") > 1 Then Range("AE" & i).Value = "OK"
```

which marks the relevant cell as `OK` once this string has been detected.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

`InStr` returns the first index of the string to search ("End-user:") into the target string (`Analysis`). You should take it, together with the lengths to calculate the substring you want. Also bear in mind that you are using `LCase` in one part but not in the other one (what provokes that the string to search will never be found as far as it contains a capital letter). A code delivering what you want:

```
Dim analysis As String : analysis = "End-user: anyone"
Dim stringToSearch as String : stringToSearch = "End-user:"
Dim finalBit As String
Dim startIndex As Integer: startIndex = InStr(LCase(analysis), LCase(stringToSearch))
If (startIndex > 0 And InStr(LCase(analysis), LCase(stringToSearch)) < Len(analysis)) Then
  Dim endIndex As Integer: endIndex = startIndex + Len(stringToSearch)
  finalBit = Mid(analysis, endIndex, Len(analysis) - endIndex + 1)
End If

'finalBit -> " anyone"
```

Answer (score 1):

More directly:

```
Dim StrMain As String
Dim StrSearch As String
Dim LngPos As Long

StrMain = "sample text End-user:kilroy"
StrSearch = "End-user:"
LngPos = InStr(StrMain, StrSearch)

If LngPos > 0 Then MsgBox Right$(StrMain, Len(StrMain) - LngPos - Len(StrSearch) + 1)
```